# collection check boxes in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

This is part of my app in rails:
How to get values in the controller of posts from the check boxes?
I want to get the array of ids got from the check boxes.
The post is created, but I can not access the array of ids got from the check boxes.

```js
class Categoryofpost < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
 belongs_to :category
end


............................

In views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @post do |p| %>
 <%= p.label :title %>
 <%= p.text_field :title %>
 <br>
 <%= p.label :body %>
 <%= p.text_area :body %>
 <br>
 <p>Related to : </p>
 <br>
 <%= p.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name %>
 <br>
 <%= p.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

```css
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates :name, uniqueness: true
 has_many :categoryofposts
 has_many :related_posts, class_name: "Post", through: :categoryofposts , source: :post
end

....................
In the posts controler
def create
  @post_params = post_params
  #@post_params[:user_id] = 1 #session[:user_id]
  @post = Post.new(@post_params)
  if @post.save
   # @cat = get_categories
   # @cat.each do |c|
   #  Categoryofpost.create(post_id: @post.id, category_id: c)
   # end
   redirect_to @post, notice: "The post has been posted successfully."
  else
   render action: :new, alert: "The post has not been posted."
  end
 end

  protected
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, categoy_ids: [])
 end
 def get_categories
  params.require(:post).permit(categoy_ids: [])
 end
```

```html
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :categoryofposts
 has_many :categories, through: :categoryofposts
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `post_params` method.It should be

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, category_ids: [])
end
```

Notice **`category_ids`**.

Comment: This works and the problem has been solved, thank you.

Comment: I have less than 16 reputation. I am so sorry.